# Need help customising partially working google sheets app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code which I cobbled from answers

```
function myFunction() { 
var sheetName = "QR CODE DATA"; // Sheet name  
var folderId = "FOLDER NAME"; // Folder ID 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); 
var url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=120x120&data="; 
var keys = ["-Tipo:", "-Ubicación:", "-# registro:", "-ID-C:", "-# Serial:", "-Pas:", "-Di I:", "-Asi:", "-RP:", "-Ar:"]; 
var values = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 11).getValues()
    .filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f) {return f})})
    .map(function(row) { row.splice(4, 1); return row;
    }); var length = values.length;

var reqs = values.map(function(e) {return {url: url + encodeURIComponent(keys.map(function(f, j) {return f + e[j]}).join("\r"))}}); 
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs); 
res.forEach(function(r, i) { 
var blob = r.getBlob().setName(length == values.length ? "row" + (i + 2) + ".png" : "row" + (length + 1) + ".png"); 
DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);   }); }
```

But this saves the PNG files into the directory as 'Row 2' 'Row 3' etc...

I would like this to use the data in Column A to name the files, but I dont know where to start.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.  I suggest you add more detail to your question.  Plus much of your code has so much chaining that its hard to figure out what you are doing and what the expected result is.

Comment: I dont know why, but I totally missed the overall functionality out of the question - my bad - I have added this in now. Thank you!

Comment: Please do not present new requirements after you have **already received an answer**. Your new requirement of decoding QR codes it out of scope of your original question. Further, you should ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Please revert your changes and post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: @doubleunary I agree with your comment. Unfortunately, from OP's initial question, I couldn't notice that OP's question is the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer for 1st question:

From your following question,

> But this saves all of the files into the directory as 'Row 2' 'Row 3' etc...
> I would like this to use the data in Column A to name the files

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "QR CODE DATA"; // Sheet name  
  var folderId = "FOLDER NAME"; // Folder ID 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=120x120&data=";
  var keys = ["-Tipo:", "-Ubicación:", "-# registro:", "-ID-C:", "-# Serial:", "-Pas:", "-Di I:", "-Asi:", "-RP:", "-Ar:"];

  // -- Modified
  var filteredValues = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 12).getDisplayValues()
    .filter(function (e) { return e.some(function (f) { return f }) });
  var filenames = filteredValues.map(function (r) { return r.splice(0, 1) });
  var values = filteredValues.map(function (row) {
    row.splice(4, 1);
    return row;
  });
  // ---

  var reqs = values.map(function (e) { return { url: url + encodeURIComponent(keys.map(function (f, j) { return f + e[j] }).join("\r")) } });
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs);
  res.forEach(function (r, i) {
    var blob = r.getBlob().setName(filenames[i]); // Modified
    DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the column "A" and they are used as the filenames of the files.

### Answer for 2nd question:

I thought that the following question is your 2nd question. When I saw your 2nd question, unfortunately, it is largely different from your 1st question.

> What I am trying to do is generate QR Codes from the values of a google sheet. The URL's that I wish to generate a QR Code for are located in Column B of a Sheet. Column A contains the name of the item the QR Code is for, so, I need to create a QR Code File as a PNG or JPEG and save it to a google drive folder, using the URL from column B, with the filename of column A

From this 2nd question, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetName = "QR CODE DATA"; // Sheet name  
  var folderId = "FOLDER NAME"; // Folder ID 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().filter(([a, b]) => a && b);
  var reqs = values.map(([, url]) => ({ url }));
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs);
  res.forEach(function (r, i) {
    var blob = r.getBlob().setName(values[i][0]);
    DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);
  });
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I wasnt clear, I need it to take the values for the QR codes from column B, but use Column A as the filename value. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Jon Bunce Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice that your 1st question is different from your actual question. About your 2nd question, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. And, can I ask you whether my answer to your 1st question was resolved?